# How to pull all "select" statements from .SQL file

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle, unix

I have a bunch of  Oracle and SQL Server .SQL scripts. I want to pull all of the `"select"` statements out of those scripts.  Then I want to pull a list of all of the tables that are referenced in them. Essentially creating a list of tables that are being used.  From there, any tables that don't exist in that list I can drop.  Has anyone done this?

Comment: In SQL Server your best bet would be to look at dependencies. It's not safe to just look for SELECT since they could be updated/deleted/inserted as well.

Comment: Word of advice, be very careful with just dropping every table that doesn't make it on your automatically generated white list. At least ask someone with knowledge of the data model to review the results manually.

Comment: (Un?)fortunately, the dependencies are all in the code. Also, those that "know" the data data model are gone.  That's why I feel my best option is to rip thru the scripts.

Comment: @JNK, yes, I would need to include the update/delete/inserts as well, but figured if I could get the SELECT's first, the rest would follow.  Just hoping someone has a some sort of script that could do this.  I figure, I'd need to format them all first to make the process simpler.

Answer (score 0):

May I suggest you turn the process around? First create a list of all of your data base tables and place that list in the environment that contains the *.sql or transact_sql code. Then write a script that searches all the scripts for each file name. It should be relatively easy to count the hits for each file name and report the results. Then files with zero hits could be removed. However, because there *may* be hidden table dependencies, you will also have to parse the code for all triggers as well. (Darn those triggers anyway!)

Comment: All of the triggers are in the *.sql scripts as well, so that's a good thing.  The list would be mighty long since I have over 400 databases across multiple servers.  Do you happen to have that script?